# Copy entire filesystem in a folder where a raid-1 array is mounted

Tags: rsync, ubuntu-12.04, raid1, copy, cp

I am trying to **migrate** from a single disk drive system to a double disk drive software raid-1 system that **already has a running system** on it. Meaning that formatting and having a new installation of ubuntu using raid-1 is NOT an option.

In this process I have to **copy the contents** from main disk (/dev/sda1) to mounted raid array (/dev/md0).

First Attempt to Copy:

```
sudo cp -dpRx / /mnt/md1
```

Second Attempt to Copy:

```
sudo rsync -avxHAXS --delete --progress / /mnt/md1
```

Both of them end with warnings. Not sure if they end successfully.

**Which command** should I use (from the two above or something else like `dd`) and with **which parameters** in order to have the md1 raid-array prepared for next reboot?

**EDIT**:
This is the warning message I got from "cp" command on my first attempt:

```
cp: cannot stat `/home/george/.gvfs': Permission denied
```

This is the error message I got from "rsync" command on my second attempt:

```
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rsync` command. It preserves everything that you would care about and you have specified everything that matters.

Then after you are finished, boot from a live media (Ubuntu has live disks too) and do the `rsync` again. It will not take long, since rsync is smart enough to skip files that are already copied. This will make sure that you are not missing anything, like files in partitions that have stuff mounted over them (`/dev` comes to mind) or already mounted encrypted home directories. It is a good idea to do it after you reboot since you may have some leftovers from applications that were running at the time of the sync when the system was up that normally get cleaned up after shut down.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a long standing bug in the kernel fuse driver.  gvfs is a virtual filesystem used to map things like network shares you browse to in nautilus.  It is only accessible to the user, not to root.  The bug is that root can't even stat() the directory to see that it is a different filesystem, and thus skip it in accordance with the `-x` flag.

You can ignore these errors.